# Swift 3 add new row to uitableviewcontroller with uialertcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I'm building a todo-list app. I'm trying to add a todo clicking an add button. It opens an alert with input title inside. I made a class for the added Item :

```
class ToDoItem
{
    var title: String


    public init(title: String)
    {
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Here is my code to add a new row :

```
func didTapAddItemButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
    {

        let alert = UIAlertController(
            title: "New to-do item",
            message: "Insert the title of the new to-do item:",
            preferredStyle: .alert)


        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: nil)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))


        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            if let title = alert.textFields?[0].text
            {
                self.addNewToDoItem(title: title)
            }
        }))


        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func addNewToDoItem(title: String)
    {

        let newIndex = listCourse?.count


        listCourse?.append(ToDoItem(title: title))


        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: newIndex!, section: 0)], with: .top)
    }
```

But I get that error :

```
Cannot convert value of type "ToDoItem" to expected argument type "myItems"
```

Here is myItems class :

```
class myItems {
    var title: String?
    var content: String?
    var date: String?
    var author: String?


    init(title: String, content: String, date: String, author: String){
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.date = date
        self.author = author
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        title <- map["title"]
        content <- map["description"]
        date <- map["pubDate"]
        author <- map["author"]
    }
}
```

This "myItems" class is used to get json data, and later I will get data from a database.

Last thing :

```
var listCourse : [myItems]?
```

listCourse is the list of cells displaying in tableViewController.

I don't understand that error I just want to add the title entered in the list

[EDIT]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "macell1", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: The error says you cannot add an object of type `ToDoItem` to an array of objects of type `myItems`. Why does `ToDoItem` even exist? You probably should be just be using the `myItems` class and delete `ToDoItem`. (By the way, `myItems` is a horrible name for a class, it sounds like an array of `myItem` objects but is really a class, very confusing. `ToDoItem` is a very good name for a class, I think.)

Comment: I did before put myItems instead of ToDoItem and it gives me an error too : 

Missing argument content, date, author

But I just want to add the title, I don't understand why I can't just use the title.

I'm going to change the name then ! thx for advice !

Comment: That's easy, just change your `init` method so as not to require all the arguments, just the `title` argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to append to listCourse an item with a wrong type. Since you defined listCourse as array of myItems instances you can append to it  instances of that class only. To fix it just change `var listCourse : [myItems]?` to `var listCourse = [ToDoItem]()`

Also fix your UITableViewDataSource method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "macell1", for: indexPath)
    let item = listCourse[indexPath.item]
    cell.textLabel.text = item.title
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer ! But then I get an error when I click on "Ok" it says that  newIndex is nil and then my app crashes

Comment: It works now I can add a row, but one last question, when the row is created it doesn't display the title i put in the textfield but the name of the row, is there something wrong in my code ?

Comment: @SamCaneau If it's working you can accept my answer. As for your next question you have to define UITableViewDataSource method: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell. If you defined it please provide the code.

Comment: I accepted your answer :) And also edit my post to provide the code of cellForRowAt